# Setting setInterval to call multiple times but gets only called once in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React Native app I want to re-render my component in a fixed time again and again after each three seconds. But it only gets called once. How can I get it called multiple times for that limited time frame. Here's my present code:

```js
 refreshData = async()=> {
  await fetch('https://myapi', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ tableData1: response.First })
        this.setState({ tableData2: response.Special })
        this.setState({ tableData3: response.Consolidation })
      })
  }
  
    componentWillMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      var today = new Date()
      var time = today.getHours()
      console.log(today.getMinutes())
      var weekDay = today.getDay()
      if ((time >= 22) && (time <= 23 )){
       if(today.getMinutes()<=30){
    
      setInterval(()=> {
        this.refreshData()
        }, 3000);
    }
    });
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging this with remote JS debugging I suggest you try the code with JS debugging stopped as it's a known issue that functions such as setTimeout and setInterval do not behave correctly in Remote JS Debugging mode and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No still does the same @hodhod96